Existence of a solution for the extended CIR model
The extended CIR model reads
$$dr_t = (\theta(t) - \kappa r_t) dt + \sigma(t) \sqrt{r_t}dW_t$$
All over the internet, we can read that "this SDE indeed has a solution". However, I cannot find any proof of this result. Indeed, the usual theorem that prove existence and uniqueness of the solution of an SDE requires both the drift and the volatility functions to be Lipschitz in space. Here, this is indeed not the case for the volatility $f(t, x):=\sigma(t)\sqrt{x}$.
So my question is the following: under which conditions over $\theta:[0,T]\to \mathbb{R}$, $\sigma:[0,T]\to \mathbb{R}$, $\kappa \in \mathbb{R}$ and $r_0$ does a solution to the CIR model exist and is unique (pathwise uniqueness)? What are the theorems behind these results?
